# "In" vs. "out of"

Tags: prepositions

Why does **out** require an additional preposition in many cases that **in** does not?

For example:

> I am in town this weekend. Next weekend I will be out of town.
>
> When the lifeguard blows the whistle, everyone must get out of the water. When he blows it again, you may get back in the water.
>
> I am in the office. At noon I will be out to lunch.

One wouldn't say "*I will be out town*" or "*get out the water*". There are also some cases where you would say "*I will be in to town*" or "*get back in to the water*", but omitting the preposition is also perfectly acceptable.

Other positional prepositions tend to require an additional preposition as well, but not "in". You go *down to the river*, *over to the next county*, *up to the 15th floor* and *off to the races*.

Why is "in" different?

Comment: related: [“based in” vs “based out of”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34101/based-in-vs-based-out-of)

Comment: the cases where you mention in to are likely cases with into

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, "into" is an option there (as I mentioned) but it's not required.

Comment: @MattЭллен while the question you linked does have "in" vs "out of", it's asking for correct usage and doesn't explore the reason why in does not use an additional preposition.

Comment: You can't say "I will be in to town"; it's not grammatical. You can say "I will be in town", or "I will get into town", but they mean different things. In this case, "in" implies a stable state of being, whereas "into" implies a movement or change of state.

Comment: @Berthilde  "I am in to town" is a stable state of being. And you certainly can say "I will be in to town". ex: "I will be in to town next week".

Comment: @Marcus_33  I'm not comfortable with "I will be in to town" although I can conceive  "I will be into town" in Berthilde's directive sense.

Comment: I think this, though very interesting, is Not A Real Question. We could spend volumes discussing prepositions and their classifications and compoundings; but **Why** any of them is used the way it is is a question to which there is no answer except **Because it is.***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Out of* is a complex preposition and merits its own entry in the OED (Oxford English Dictionary), separate from the entry for *out*. It has numerous uses, but in your first two examples it means the opposite of *in*. In your third example, the use of *to* is rather different, and not really relevant to the main question.

*Out of* has a long history, but this extract from the OED’s etymological note may help to answer your question more fully:

> The history of *out of* is partly parallel to that of *in to*, with the
>   differences that the latter is now written *into* as one word, and that
>   *out of* is the opposite, not only of *into*, but also of the static *in*.
>   One reason why *out of* has not needed to be written as one word may be
>   that the distinction now made between *into* and *in to* is in the case of
>   *out* expressed by *out of* and *out from*: thus ‘they came in to me, into
>   my house’, ‘he went out from me, out of my house’.

There has been discussion in the comments on another answer about the use of *out* followed immediately by a noun phrase. *Out* is used in this way with two main meanings. The first (1) is ‘from within, away from’, as in this 1992 citation from Toronto’s ‘Globe and Mail’:

> When you become useless, you're out the door.

The OED describes this use as being formerly poetical and now regional and nonstandard.

The second main meaning (2) is ‘outside, beyond’, as in this 1977 citation from J P Donleavy:

> A thrush chirping its evening song in the first darkness just out the
>   window.

The OED describes this use merely ‘now nonstandard’. This 1991 citation seems to me to confirm this view:

> He spent too much time boozing down the pub. Too much time out the
>   house.

It may be that *out* + noun phrase is Standard American English in sense (1), but nonstandard, as in British English, in sense (2).

**EDIT:**

Research in 1997 into the use of *out the door* and *out the window*, reported in ‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’, ‘found ample evidence of their use in spoken discourse and in published fiction, though this doesn’t yet guarantee their place in British written style generally.’

Comment: Thanks for summarizing this, Barrie. All I would add (as I mentioned in my answer) is that complex prepositions are generally analyzed as consisting of adverb + preposition, and not preposition + preposition.

Comment: Excellent roundup (we can see you're a professional!). To be honest, what I like best is that later edit. I ***know*** *"out the door"* is a bit "iffy", but how to convince anyone else of that? Answer: look to ‘The Cambridge Guide’.

Comment: *Out* by itself is used in AE as a preposition in the sense *through in order to get outside*.

Comment: You mean saying "he threw it out the window" is considered informal in the U.K.? That's surprising! Actually, sense 1 is standard in the U.S. only for a very small class of nouns. For example, "he went out the office" sounds clearly wrong to me, where as "door" or "window" are fine.

Comment: @PeterShor: It may well be so only for _door_ and _window_.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: I made a comment under the question, mentioning that _out_ is often used by itself in AmE when it means _out through_, so, doors and windows, yes, but also similar constructs, like "I crawled out the hatch while water flowed out the nozzle."

Comment: @J.R. That would be sense (1) then.

Answer (score 1):

This is because "out" here is not a preposition, it's an adverb. According to the OED's entry OUT, prep., "out" is no longer used as a preposition in Standard English, though it is in widespread use in nonstandard and regional varieties, and it is apparently now seen as a standard use in American English. For example, in American English you might hear

> I took it out the closet

whereas in most varieties of British English we would say "I took it out of the closet".

The other examples you give are also all adverbs followed by prepositions, not two prepositions linked together. "Down", "up", "over", and "off" can all be prepositions in standard English, but not with the same meanings as they have in the examples you quote. For example, "I went over the river" (*over* is a preposition) is different in meaning from "I went over to the river" (*over* is an adverb). However, as with "out", you may see them in non-standard varieties being used prepositionally with the same sense as the adverb-preposition construction. For example, my grandmother would have said

> I went down my friend's house

meaning the same thing as

> I went down to my friend's house.

So, in summary, "out" requires "of" because it is not functioning as a preposition, but as an adverb, and therefore cannot take an object. "In" is a preposition, and therefore can take an object.

Edit: see also Barrie's answer, where he points out that the combination "out of" functions as a kind of compound preposition - it has a single meaning which is based on the meanings of the adverb and the preposition.

Comment: "He ran out the door" is a perfectly fine example of out as a preposition in standard English. Why does he run out the door, but out of the house?

Comment: @Marcus_33 No reason to throw the baby out the window a frisbee.

Comment: @Marcus_33: "He ran out the door" is not standard English, although it's very commonly heard, particularly in American varieties. Perhaps it's starting to become a standard usage in the U.S.? I'm in the U.K., and I can tell you that you would never see "he ran out the door" in standard written English, though it's not uncommon in the spoken language. But I'm going to amend my answer to make clearer what I mean.

Comment: No, that is not true: “He ran out the door” is perfectly standard, just as much throwing something out the window is — and trust me, it is. OED: 1972 D. E. Westlake Cops & Robbers (1973) iii. 46 ― He looked out the windshield. 
1973 Black World Aug. 55/2 ― He slid on back out the kitchen door. 
1975 New Yorker 29 Sept. 43/2 ― Mrs. Santana and her children contribute to the refuse by throwing their trash and garbage out their windows.

Comment: @tchrist - do we mean the same thing by "standard"? If a British student wrote "He ran out the door" in an academic paper, it would be marked as poor grammar. It's not standard in written British English. The OED marks all uses of "out" as a preposition as "regional", "nonstandard", or "obsolete/rare", so it seems that it's not considered standard in any variety.

Comment: Read my OED citations.  It is certainly standard English, which your comment above disclaimed.

Comment: *Ran out the door*, *looked out the window*, *threw it out the porthole* are perfectly acceptable in the US, and I believe in any formal discourse, to indicate the path followed rather than the destination departed. Other prepositions serve similar uses: *down the mountain*, for instance, or even more interestingly, *across the bridge* (which is distinctly different from *across the river*).

Comment: Again, I'm not sure we mean the same thing by "standard English". I mean this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_English

Comment: Surely you do not pretend that “Standard” English somehow means the British flavor?! That would be incredibly insular.

Comment: I have tried to cover this point in my answer. Any misunderstanding may arise from the two different meanings of _out_ + noun phrase. Standard English does not, of course, just mean the British variety, and I trust that this is not what Berhilde meant.

Comment: @tchrist: did you read the Wikipedia article on the meaning of the term "Standard English"? It is a term of art that has a specific meaning. There is standard British English, and standard American English, and they're very similar although with some few differences. The point is that "out" as a preposition is nonstandard in all varieties of English. That doesn't mean it's uncommon,  or indeed that it's "wrong", just that it's not an accepted use in the particular sociolect that we call "Standard English".

Comment: I agree that *out* in the sense *outside (of)* is non-standard in both BE and AE. But in AE *out* in the sense I described above -- *out the window* -- is not merely standard but preferred in all registers.

Comment: @StoneyB: that's really interesting to hear. As of the last update, OED disagrees with you, but I wouldn't be surprised to see them re-label at least the sense you mention, if not both senses, as "standard in American usage" (or something similar) sometime soon.

Comment: I don't have a sub to OED; but log on to COCA, [here](http://corpus.byu.edu/), and compare results for *out the door* and *out of the door*. (Of course, these are not phrases for which there's much **occasion** in formal use!) BNC, at the same site, confirms your observations about use in BE.

Comment: @Berthilde: if the OED says that, it's wrong. As a native American speaker, I agree with StoneyB and tchrist that "out" as a preposition in the phrases "out the door", "out the window", "out the chimney", "out the porthole", "out the escape hatch", and so on, is Standard American English. (Not in the sense of "outside the door", but in the sense of "(going) out of the door".)

Comment: What @PeterShor said. Another way I'd explain it is that, here in the U.S., _out_ can be used on its own when it means _out through_ – which is why you can run _out the door_ but you run _out of the house_. Also, I found this note at [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/out): "In American English and spoken British English _out_ itself is commonly used as a preposition, but many British people consider that this use is not correct: _I looked out the window_."

Comment: Well, my only response is to say that I took my information from a reputable source. OED tends to label words based on how the find them being used, so they must have had a reason to call it nonstandard, but I'm happy to bow to the users of American English on here who tell me that it's used in formal written American English. It's kind of a side-note to my answer anyway, since the point I made about "out" being an adverb in these constructions still stands! But I'll edit to reflect this discussion. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Berthilde: it is certainly a reputable source, and I'm surprised that they're wrong.

Comment: @PeterShor: I guess that, because they base their definitions on evidence of usage, they just didn't find enough evidence of its use in formal American writing yet. I can imagine that changing pretty quickly, given how widespread you say the use now is. But perhaps someone should write in and question the tag?

Comment: @Berthilde: it's also possible they didn't actually ask the right questions, and got the wrong impression of its formality. The restriction of *out* as a preposition to *out through* is fairly subtle. For example, *"I drove the car *out the garage*" is incorrect (although probably used informally), but *"I went out the garage"* is fine if you mean you walked from the kitchen out through the garage into the driveway.