# The meaning of "be based in"

Tags: meaning

When a company says: "*All applicants must be based in the UK.*", what does it mean? In which aspects should we be based on the UK?

Comment: Did you look up *all* and *base* in a dictionary?

Comment: yes.I know the meaning of all and base.It is clear but you didn't understand my question.you just thought of voting.

Comment: The sentence says "*based **in***", you're asking about "*based **on***".

Comment: You may also want to know that when asking questions in StackExchange websites, *you must include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. **Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic***.

Comment: I agree that it's not absolutely clear. See the original question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [“based in” vs “based out of ”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34101/based-in-vs-based-out-of)

Answer (score 2):

I believe it means that all applicants should be residents of UK.

Comment: Yes. As Nagaraju Kanapuram says: Your home must be in the UK. For the future, you will probably get better answers for basic English questions on the [English Language Learner's Stack Exchange Site](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you Nagaraju and Jim.I really appreciate you to spend time to answer my q.And thank you Jim to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily find your answer in a dictionary. Here's what you'd find if you looked up ***base*** in [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/base_1) for example:

> **base**<sup>1</sup> `verb`
>   `[transitive usually passive]`    to have your main place of work, business etc in a particular place: 
>   *The paper had intended to base itself in London.*
>
> **be based in something**
>   *The new organization will be based in Dallas.*
>   ➔ based

[Reference: http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/base_1 ]

***P.S.*** Another good thing to remember ***all the time, with all languages*** is to type all words fully with correct spelling. It's never appropriate to say "*q*" instead of "*question*".

Comment: But I saw this meaning before,and I couldn't understand the meaning of "based in" with this definition too.  :(

Comment: @mahtab You're welcome. Use the up arrow button to *upvote* an answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: My reputation is less than 15!so I couldn't vote!sorry...