# Information that the reports can work 'off' or 'of'

Tags: differences

Should it be

> Last years data set contains information that the reports can work off

or

> Last years data set contains information that the reports can work of

?

Comment: Which one do you think it should be?

Comment: Clearly it's "information that the reports can work off of".

Comment: I didn't think reports were able to work; reports are simply produced for people to use.

Comment: *from*, goddamnit. I'll hear no more of this *off of*.

Comment: @MattЭллен: Have it your way: "information that the reports can work from off of."

Comment: Is there more context to these phrases?

Comment: @Mark Beadles: I don't see how "more context" can make any difference, but if anyone can post an answer showing how OP's two alternatives could each be more "suitable" in different contexts (or could mean different things) I will definitely upvote it.

Comment: At the very least, a complete sentence that these phrases are to be used in would let us know if there is a different wording altogether that might be suitable.

Comment: @Mark Beadles: But OP isn't *asking* for our "creative rewrites" - he wants to know which of his two alternatives is correct. Not that this prevents anyone from endorsing, for example, Reg or Matt's suggested alternatives in their answer.

Comment: per Barry's comment this question can be improved or closed. It currently lacks any evidence of effort or research.

Comment: I improved and added more detail but tbh I don't think it helps much, the question is relatively straightforward w/o context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(The earlier question [“Based on” instead of “based off of”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15081/based-on-instead-of-based-off-of) covers some similar ground).

Some people (myself among them) dislike *"Data the reports can work **off of**"*, but that's not one of OP's proposed alternatives, so let it pass.

Of OP's two, *"**of**"* would never be acceptable. For many people, *"**off**"* would be okay, but I think most would prefer *"**with**"*, *"**on**"*, or *"**from**"*. My preference is for...

> *"Data the reports can work **from**"*

There's not necessarily any semantic/grammatical argument for any particular preposition here, and all those I've emboldened (apart from ***of***) are actually used by competent speakers. But I personally feel it makes more sense for *actual programs* to work ***on*** or ***with*** data because they do "more" with that data. To some extent, reports can be said to just list data ***from*** a database.

(I changed OP's *"information"* to *"data"* because I think one of the purposes of reports is *to turn data into [accessible] information.*)

Comment: I think that *reports* in the OP example **does** refer to people: subordinate staff are sometimes referred to as *reports* because they *report to* someone else. It's BizSpeak I particularly hate, so I called it out; but so far @MichaelDurrant hasn't qualified its use.

Comment: @Andrew: If that's the case then it's an absolutely appalling question! I've *never* come across that meaning - how on earth could OP expect us to *assume* it? It doesn't affect my answer though - if that "perverse" sense of "reports" was in fact intended, my answer clearly implies that ***on*** or ***with*** would be at least "slightly better" choices from my point of view. But that's effectively a personal stylistic choice, and all alternatives would remain "valid" and could reasonably be used by competent speakers (which is more than I can say for that BizSpeak meaning! :)

Comment: no, no, it is data.  I guess you were thinking 'reports' as in 'direct reports', i.e. the people that report directly to someone else, but no this is not what I meant at all, I meant reports for data :)  I'm accepting 'for'

Comment: @Michael: I think your last word there must be a typo. Regardless of whether the "reports" are people or documents, they can't work **for** "information".

Comment: @MichaelDurrant That's a shame! I was so hoping that some flunkies were going to have to work off some information surfeit that had gone to their waistlines. :)