# Meaning of "take your mind off"

Tags: expressions

I came across this phrase on the website: http://www.bspcn.com/about/

> Over all, this site is sure to be appreciated by anyone that needs to take his or her mind off of more pressing matters.

I looked it up into the dictionary, and the explanation for *take his mind off* is "if an activity takes someone's mind off their problems, it stops them from thinking about it".

But why does *of* exist in the sentence above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between get "off of" and "off"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101683/).Also [How can I explain to people that the phrase “off of ” is grammatically incorrect?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/619/) and [What is the meaning of “build off of”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102057/), among others.

Comment: To distract you from other, weightier issues.  When you say off "of"  the "of" is beginning a prepositional phrase that is filled in by whatever the "weightier issue" is that you are distracting yourself from.  "off of work." "off of your marriage." "off of your father's death."  Again, the preposition acts adverbially to say what you got off of.  In your sentence, you are getting your mind off of more pressing matters. Finally, if the idiom is what bothers you, "off of" is an English idiom which allows for two consecutive prepositions.  "Off" is not used in the literal sense, calling for "of"