# Use of "off of" or "off" with some verbs in place of "on"

Tags: prepositions

I have noticed a trend among younger native speakers of English to use the proposition(s) "off/off of" in place of "on." The most common one is the verb *base*. I have just heard it with *go*, which I can accept. An example would be "I have nothing to go on," which in the newer form would be "I have nothing to go off of." Another verb is *build*. My question is whether others have noticed this as well. It appears to me that this lexical change will become normal pretty quickly.

Comment: *"off of"* is the antithesis of *"on to"*.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Based on" instead of "based off of"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15081/based-on-instead-of-based-off-of). Or [Difference between get “off of” and “off”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101683/difference-between-get-off-of-and-off). Or [How can I explain to people that the phrase “off of ” is grammatically incorrect?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/619/how-can-i-explain-to-people-that-the-phrase-off-of-is-grammatically-incorrect)

Comment: It's a common colloquial variant. The reason you hear it among youngsters is not because it is a new expression, but because kids are more likely to say slangy, ungrammatical things.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed *go off* where I would say *go on*, meaning *happen*, as in "What's going off?". I started noticing this about twenty years ago, soon after I moved to Yorkshire, so I wasn't sure whether it was a change in English, or just a Yorkshire expression.

I haven't noticed the others, but I can quite imagine them: they seem to me to represent a change of metaphor from BUILD UPON to START FROM (*off of* = *from*).