# Based off of vs. Based off

Tags: grammar

Yes, I have seen the amazing thread [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15081/based-on-instead-of-based-off-of), which discusses mainly "**based on**" vs. "**based off of**", and it also (vaguely) touches on the fact that "**based off**" can actually be equivalent to "**based off of**"

I just wanted to get a clear answer: is it enough to say "**based off**", instead of "**based off of**"?

I.e. can I just say:

- *the chart I am working off for my decision-making*"

instead of

- *the chart I am working off of for my decision making*?

Whenever I hear "off of", my ears explode and I just don't understand why people go through the pain of pronouncing such an awkward expression, when logically, "based off" should be enough?

I am basically looking here on this forum for a permission to say "based off" instead of "based off of" going forward: which will actually significantly contribute to my mental well being :).

**Is "based off" grammatically correct?**

Comment: You could always just extend the final "f" sound so that people might think you said "off of" when you really only said "off" - then you'll both be happy.

Comment: Thank you @KillingTime , that made me smile :)

Comment: 'The chart I am working from / off / off of' is a different example, and parallelism isn't guaranteeable. But the previous thread shows the state of play; there isn't a grammar czar to say yea or nay here. 'Based on' is indisputably correct in all registers.

Comment: Here are [some ideas](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/619/how-can-i-explain-to-people-that-the-phrase-off-of-is-grammatically-incorrect). "Off of" is not ungrammatical. Plus, there are transatlantic differences.

Comment: @fev: Thank you so much for that thread, that fully and completely answers my question. Also, I will sleep better, knowing that simply "off" is fine and "off of" is not necessary (albeit allowed).